# Resize Image with browser display

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a website I am using carousel bootstrap, the website is mobile friendly, however the only problem I have got is that the slider images do not shrink with the image, so it ends up making them look stretched out. I have tried max-width and max-height 100% but it does not work any advise?

If you resize your browser you will get what I mean, the header height does not shrink.

This is an example of the index page:

http://pastebin.ca/2648252

This is my css

http://pastebin.ca/2648251

Code was too long to post here, Can be seen on there no download required.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `max-height` auto instead of `100%`?

Comment: Looks like you have your img height explicitly set on your carousel img. In order for the images to be responsive and maintain aspect ratio, just set display:block; width:100%; height:auto on those images.

Comment: awww man we can't even preview the HTML, Fiddle would have been way more helpful.

Comment: I tried fiddler but there are too much styles and stuff. I can send you through email if you would like to have a go.

Comment: Max-height auto? Where would I put that iv tried diffrent sections, but I dont know where to put it exactly.

Comment: I have added to fiddler but no images dont know how to add them.

http://jsfiddle.net/K56hT/

Comment: Put your images on an accessible server - not uploaded to jsfiddle.

Comment: I have uploaded 2 pics which are required to see. if you need more do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `img-responsive` class to the carousel images..

```
<img src="/images/logo-1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
```

### http://www.bootply.com/117666

Comment: Hi ill give you an example of one of the images

</div>
   <div class="item">
          <img src="images/followus.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="contactus.html" role="button">Learn More</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

I have added the class="img-responsive" but it doesn't work. do i have to add anything to the css?

Comment: You're css is explicitly setting a height of 500px on your images. Line 60 of your css on the fiddle. That css is loaded after your bootstrap css so it will override properties of the 'img-responsive' class.

Comment: Not that I see. There is no overriding CSS is this bootply -- http://www.bootply.com/render/117666

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K56hT/5/

I have removed the height 500px, also added the class, however I am getting a grey box below the image that is not getting used. Any clue why this could be? Also when resizing the image shrinking it, it goes under the navbar. thanks Also all changed have been made to fiddle.

Comment: Is it possible for me to get the CSS styling for it and just copy it in will that work??